# Как в C#(WPF) передать переменную при событии MouseDown?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, visual-studio

У меня есть WrapPanel, с помощью `Children[0].MouseDown += *Событие*` я хочу добавить событие в которое можно было бы передать переменную, в будущем я планирую там послать запрос на сервер и нужно чтобы была переменная с id ([http://сайт/api/rooms/id](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/api/rooms/id) ), но стандартная функция типа

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Source.ToString());    
    }
```

не хочет принимать в аттрибуты `int i` и в `MouseDown` происходит ошибка.
[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

В общем какое событие можно навесить на элемент чтобы можно было при нажатии отправить id?

Comment: `при нажатии отправить id` - научитесь использовать команды!

Comment: Вы можете использовать свойство Tag любого элемента для хранения дополнительных параметров которые можно использовать в событиях при их вызове.

Comment: Можно както при создании изборажения, в фигурные скобки определить событие нажатия и указать ему метод?

`stack.Children.Add(new Image {Height = 225, Width = 236, Source = logo, Stretch = Stretch.Fill,});`

Comment: @Rootware А как узнать tag если у Imag'а нет имени и он создан через new Image?

Comment: @Аладушка в вызываемое событие добавляется объект вызвавший это событие. находится он в `object sender`.

Comment: @Rootware но sender принимает только `Equals; GetHashType; GetType; ToString`

Comment: @Аладушка потому что вы его не привели к необходимому вам типу. Object тип - это обобщённый тип для всех объектов (классы, контролы и т.д.). Вам необходимо почитать введение в ООП программирование. У вас явный пробел с пониманием переменных и объектов. Например приведение к типу Button выглядит так: `Button button = (Button) sender;`.

Comment: @Rootware о дааа, я с этим колотился весь вечер, спасибо огромное, sender то- что нужно. Я просто с javascript прыгаю на c# и сложно сразу на двух лодках держаться не оступаясь, то что работает в js не работает в С#, очень бесит)

Comment: @Rootware а еще вопрос, можно как то при создании new Image задать ему метод типа MouseDown? Просто если много изображений то для кажой это писать глупо. В XAML все просто написал пару строчек и все пашет а в коде c# с этим проблемы какието.

Comment: @Аладушка да, конечно. Если этот элемент поддерживает такое событие, то добавьте при создании в его свойство соответствующий ивент.

Comment: вот именно что ничего кроме bindings там не нашел

Comment: Ох ребята, ну творите же вы тут. С таким подходом я вам советую забыть про WPF и использовать WinForms, там это уместно. Но WPF... Создание элементов через код... Не использовать привязки... Извините, но это издевательство над бедным WPF, ибо он заточен именно на работу с привязками (я уже молчу про MVVM), работой с свойствами, коллекциями и так далее, но не как не работай с контролами через код. Так вы изобретаете себе кучу гемороя, практически отказываетесь от стилей, от XAML'a в целом, а тут как я и говорил, какой смысл использовать тогда WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно както при создании изборажения, в фигурные скобки определить событие нажатия и указать ему метод? `stack.Children.Add(new Image {Height = 225, Width = 236, Source = logo, Stretch = Stretch.Fill,});`

Можно:

```
Image image = new Image { Height = 225, Width = 236, Source = logo, Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
image.MouseDown += (s, e) => MyMethod(myId); // MyMethod — ваш метод для отправки, myId — ваш id или любой другой параметр
stack.Children.Add(image);
```

Хотя, если что-то должно вести себя как кнопка, то оно и должно быть кнопкой, WPF дает нам для этого все возможности: стилизуйте обычный `Button` — поместите ему изображение в `Content` или даже в шаблон.

Ну и, как вам подсказали в комментариях, желательно разделить логику и представление, использовать всю мощь автогенерации контролов с помощью `ItemsPanel`. Тогда ваш код превратится во что-то вроде такого:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding SendCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                    Template="{StaticResource MySendButtonTemplate}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

И кучка небольших классов (настоящее ООП ;) ) VM, представляющих ваши объекты из предметной области вашей программы.